# Как сделать разделение элементов в ListView?

Tags: android, listview, сортировка, list

Нужно разделение элементов в ListView (ну или в чем получиться), по дате.
Как это можно реализовать? 
К примеру вот есть список контактов который разделяется по буквам.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть таких множество уже [готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=recyclerview+section&type=).

Answer (score 0):

В ваш item шаблон добавьте divider и textView.

Сделайте их `View.GONE;`

Далее в адаптере сохраняете 1ю букву содержимого имени("А...") и показываете его в textView. (1й элемент массива)

Проверяете элемент по следующей позиции. Если сохранённая буква отличается от той, что сейчас проверяется, отображаете уже в этом итеме в textView новую букву("Б...") и уже сравниваете остальные буквы уже с ней.(2й элемент массива)

Если же 1 буква содержимого имени 3-го элемента равна нашей, оставляете textView спрятанным. Примерная суть понятна?